# Model single activity requiring different resource types

Tags: process, resources, simpy

Process 3 requires both resources A and B, and can only start after process 1 (by resource A) and process 2 (by resource B) have been completed. The code below seems to perform as desired, but the if / else statement looks very inelegant. Is there a 'better' way of accomplishing the same behavior?

```
def orchestration(self):
    # Request resources A and B
    req_resourceA = self.resourceA.request()
    req_resourceB = self.resourceB.request()

    # Wait until first resource is available (will change throughout simulation)
    available_rec = yield.self.env.any_of([req_resourceA, req_resourceB])

    if list(available_rec.keys())[0] == resourceA:
        proc1 = self.env.process(self.process1())
        yield resourceB
        proc2 = self.env.process(self.process2())
    else:
        proc2 = self.env.process(self.process2())
        yield resourceA
        proc1 = self.env.process(self.process1())
  
    # Start process 3 only after processes 1 and 2 have been completed
    yield proc1 & proc2
    yield self.env.timeout(process3_time)

    # Manually release both resource requests
    self.resourceA.release(req_resourceA)
    self.resourceB.release(req_resourceB)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this solution I run process 1 and 2 in parallel instead of in sequence and used a all_of to wait for both processes to finish.  This should reduce some idle time for the resources.  Process 1 and 2 also grabs the resource they need, but do not release it.  Instead they return the request so it can be passed to process 3.  I pass the resource requests to process 3 thinking process 3 would know when to release each resource.  for example process 3 could release resource A, do some more stuff, then release resource B

```
"""
One way steps can be sequcenced

In this example the pre steps are run in parallel 
rather the sequentially

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

from urllib import request
import simpy
import random

def process1(env, resPool):
    """
    Simple process that grabs a resource and does some processing

    The resource request is not released, but returned to the calling process
    """

    resRequest = resPool.request()

    yield resRequest

    print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 1 has resource and started')

    yield env.timeout(random.randint(1,5))

    print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 1 has finish')

    return resRequest
    
def process2(env, resPool):
    """
    another simple process that grabs a resource and does some processing

    The resource request is not released, but returned to the calling process
    """

    resRequest = resPool.request()

    yield resRequest

    print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 2 has resource and started')

    yield env.timeout(random.randint(1,5))

    print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 2 has finish')

    return resRequest

def process3(env, resourceAPool, requestA, resourceBPool, requestB):
    """
    Final process that reuses resouces from process1 and process2
    which this process is dependant on
    """

    print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 3 started')

    yield env.timeout(random.randint(1,5))

    resourceAPool.release(requestA)
    resourceBPool.release(requestB)

    print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 3 finish')

def endToEndProcessing(env, resourceAPool, resourceBPool):
    """
        the end to end processes
        where process1 and process2 must complete before process 3 can start
    """

    while True:
        # start each pre process, but do not yeild so they runn in parallel
        proc1 = env.process(process1(env,resourceAPool))
        proc2 = env.process(process2(env,resourceBPool))

        # wait for both processes to finish
        preProcesses = yield env.all_of([proc1, proc2])

        # get resource requests and pass to process 3
        reqA = preProcesses[proc1]
        reqB = preProcesses[proc2]

        yield env.process(process3(env, resourceAPool, reqA, resourceBPool, reqB))


env = env = simpy.Environment()
resourceAPool = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)
resourceBPool = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=1)

env.process(endToEndProcessing(env, resourceAPool, resourceBPool))

env.run(100)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Michael, this reads / flows better than my original attempt. Few questions to make sure I fully understand. (1) My entity flows through the different process steps, then exist the simulation - therefore, I should remove the while True statement, correct? (2) How should I interpret preProcesses)?  (<class 'simpy.events.ConditionValue'> - a dictionary with values equal to the return statement of the corresponding processes?

Comment: so you can add a entity parameter to endToEndProcessing and take out the while loop and call it from another process to do just one entity
With all_of the list of processes you pass to it will be the keys of the preProcesses. and the values will be the values returned by the process.  With any_of, only the first processes that fire are in the dict, not the whole list.  You can get more then one because one or more may fire on the same time tick.  Any thing that fires on the same time tic is said to fire a the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complicated answer

Here each process is run asynchronously using resources and stores to control the running of the processes.  The advantages here is you can have more then one of each process and by controlling the number of each process you can do some load balancing.

The basic flow is process 1 an 2 grab their resource, do their processing any pass the resource to process 3 via 2 stores, 1 store for resource A and 1 for resource B.  process 3 then releases the resources when finish

```
"""
One way steps can be sequenced

In this example the all the processes are run asyc
using a couple of stores to control when process 3 can run 

The advanatage to this is allows for load balancing.

For example if process1 takes twice as long as process2
and process2 takes twice as long as process3, then
best resource use might be with 4 process1's 2 process2's and 1 process3

Programmer: Michael R. Gibbs
"""

from urllib import request
import simpy
import random

process3Cnt = 0

def process1(env, id, resPool, reqStore):
    """
    Simple process that grabs a resource and does some processing

    The resource request is not released, but returned to a store
    which process 3 uses to know when it can start
    """

    while True:
        resRequest = resPool.request()

        yield resRequest

        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 1 id:{id} has resource and started')

        yield env.timeout(random.randint(1,16))

        reqStore.put(resRequest)

        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 1 id:{id} has finish')

def process2(env, id, resPool, reqStore):
    """
    Another Simple process that grabs a resource and does some processing

    The resource request is not released, but returned to a store
    which process 3 uses to know when it can start
    """

    while True:
        resRequest = resPool.request()

        yield resRequest

        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 2 id:{id} has resource and started')

        yield env.timeout(random.randint(1,8))

        reqStore.put(resRequest)

        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 2 id:{id} has finish')

    
def process3(env, id, resourceAPool, requestAStore, resourceBPool, requestBStore):
    """
    Final process that reuses resouces from process1 and process2
    which this process is dependant on

    The resouce requests are passed to proccess 3 using stores
    """

    global process3Cnt

    while True:

        storeAReq = requestAStore.get()
        storeBReq = requestBStore.get()

        # wait for both store request to finish
        storeRequests = yield env.all_of([storeAReq, storeBReq])

        # get the resource requests
        requestA = storeRequests[storeAReq]
        requestB = storeRequests[storeBReq]

        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 3 id:{id} started')

        yield env.timeout(random.randint(1,4))

        # release the resources
        resourceAPool.release(requestA)
        resourceBPool.release(requestB)

        print(f'{env.now:0.2f} process 3 id:{id} finish')

        process3Cnt += 1


env = env = simpy.Environment()
resourceAPool = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=4)
resourceBPool = simpy.Resource(env, capacity=2)

requestAStore = simpy.Store(env)
requestBStore = simpy.Store(env)


# try changing the number of each process to maximize the throughput 

#launch process1
for id in range(1,5):
    env.process(process1(env, id, resourceAPool, requestAStore))

#launch process2
for id in range(1,3):
    env.process(process2(env, id, resourceBPool, requestBStore))

#launch process3
for id in range(1,2):
    env.process(process3(env, id, resourceAPool, requestAStore, resourceBPool, requestBStore))

env.run(100)

print(f'Process 3 ran {process3Cnt} times')
```